# Calculating torsion in $\pi_i(S^{2n})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $n>1$.

> I want to prove that $\pi_i(S^n)$ has no $p$-torsion for $i<n+2p-3$.

For odd $n$ this is Proposition 6.26 in McCleary's book (p.206). He mentions afterward the result for even-dimensional spheres can be obtained by 'similar arguments'.

His argument for odd $n$ went like this:

- There is a fibration $K(\Bbb Z,n-1)\to X\to S^n$ and $X$ has the same homotopy groups as $S^n$ in degrees $\geq n+1$ and zero in degrees $\leq n$.
- It suffices to determine the connectivity of $H^*(X;\Bbb Z_p)$ because then we can apply the *Hurewicz-Serre theorem* which says: $$H_i(X;\Bbb Z_p)=0 \text{ for } 0<i<m \implies \pi_i(X)\otimes \Bbb Z_p =0 \text{ for } i<m$$
- The $\Bbb Z_p$ cohomology of the fiber is known: It's a free graded-commutative algebra on certain elements, and starts with $H^{n-1}(K(\Bbb Z,n-1);\Bbb Z_p)=\Bbb Z_p\cdot\iota_{n-1}$. Since $n$ is odd, all the powers $(\iota_{n-1})^k$ exist as well. The class of next highest degree is $P^1(\iota_{n-1})$.
- $\iota_{n-1}$ transgresses to a generator $u\in H^n(S^n;\Bbb Z_p)$, hence the derivation property implies $d((\iota_{n-1})^k)=u\otimes (\iota_{n-1})^{k-1}$ for $k<p$, so none of those products persist to $E_\infty$.
- This implies that the class of least degree which persists to $E_\infty$ is $P^1(\iota_{n-1})\in H^{n-1+2(p-1)}(X;\Bbb Z_p)$.
- Thus $H^*(X;\Bbb Z_p)$ starts in degree $n-1+2(p-1)=n+2p-3$ where it is $\Bbb Z_p$. Now the Hurewicz-Serre theorem implies the claim.

**It is not at all clear to me how to transfer this argument to the case that $n$ is even.**

If $n$ is even, there are no powers of $\iota_{n-1}$ by graded commutativity, so the product $u\otimes \iota_{n-1}$ does not get killed. And actually this element comes from the fact that $\pi_{2n-1}(S^n) = \Bbb Z$, so there is no way it could be killed.
There seems to be no way of applying Hurewicz-Serre because the conncetivity of $H^*(X;\Bbb Z_p)$ is terrible. **Can this situation be remedied?**

*Remarks:*

- The fibration is obtained by pulling back the pathspace fibration $K(\Bbb Z, n-1)\to P \to K(\Bbb Z,n)$ along a map $S^n\to K(\Bbb Z,n)$ which is a $\pi_n$-isomorphism.
- I also tried using another space instead of $X$ - one which has the same homotopy groups as $S^n$ in degrees $\geq 2n$ and zero below, but in that case we don't know much about fiber or base space.

Comment: I think this question fits better in Mathoverflow.

Comment: @YotasTrejos this is a proposition in a lower-level graduate text. It is unlikely to be appropriate at MO.

Comment: Take a look at Serre's "Homologie singuliere des espaces fibres", chapter V.6.  The idea is that by considering the fibration $S^{n-1} \to V_{n,2} \to S^n$, where $V_{n,2}$ is the unit tangent bundle of $S^n$, one can relate the homotopy of even spheres to odd spheres.  This is because the first nonzero homotopy of $V_{n,2}$ is in degree $n - 2$; the other cases follows from the Freudental suspension theorem.

Comment: Thank you, @JHF, I had tried using that fibration as well but couldn't get anything out of it. The issue there is that $H_{4n-1}(V)=\Bbb Z$. We can conclude that $\pi_i(V)$ consists only of $2$-torsion for $i<4n-1$, but that doesn't seem to be good enough.

Comment: At the prime $p = 2$, we have $n + 2p - 3 = n + 1$, so the conclusion is just saying $\pi_i S^n$ has no $2$-torsion for $i \leq n$.  But this is clear since $\pi_i S^n = 0$ if $i < n$ and $\pi_n S^n \cong \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$.